# Copy path to directory from windows explorer?

Tags: windows, terminal, windows-explorer

I'm new to windows (a strange statement but true). I like using shells, but sometimes windows is set up to use the file explore.

Is there a way of copying a path from the file explorer... so that I can go back to using a shell?

Comment: Click on the file explorer address bar, select the path, press Ctrl+C or right-click then click on Copy

Comment: Hmm... it seems like you need to click on the blank space to the right of the address bar, since clicking on the address bar itself pops up a drop down to change your path.

Comment: Yes on the right side of the address bar. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yep, thanks, that's perfect. I tried clicking on the address bar to start with - but was confused by these dropdowns. Thanks again.

Comment: If you want file paths (and or folder paths), highlight them in the explorer.  Hold down [SHIFT], then right click.  "Copy as path" has been a part of the windows explorer for a long time.  You need to hold down shift when right clicking to see it. [Here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/131557-copy-path-file-explorer-windows-10-a.html) are some even better tips.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Reddy for their answer: you need to click to the space to the right of the address bar.

I have drawn a beautiful and informative diagram:

[image]

Comment: Dyslexia is a horrible disease (I have it).  What your diagram shows is the right and not the left vs the @Reddy comment at the top of your post.

Comment: Aha thanks. I'm not sure I have dyslexia... probably just dysphasia and inattention!

Answer (score 0):

The way that works is to select the drive in the My Computer and do a rename and copy and paste the path from there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).